# Excel: Dynamic Dependant List

Tags: excel, validation, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a stock take list in Excel (Only program available to the company).

I would like to add 2 drop-down lists;

1. Category (I.e. Cleaning, Gas, Electrical, Plumbing)
2. Item

When Category (i.e. Electrical) is picked from drop-down 1, then only the electrical items show in the Item drop-down.

I have a Item list with Category and Item as headers.

When doing my research, the only way I can see it working, is having a separate list (table) for each Category.

Is there a way of making this work, while having only 1 Item list covering all categories?

Comment: The answer is yes and no. It's no because your drop-downs need lists, at least one list per drop-down but actually one Items list for each selected category. This can't be avoided. But it's yes because you can create the lists on the fly by filtering a master that has all the items. There are plenty of step-by-step instructions for this on the web. Look for "interdependent validation drop-downs".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dependent dropdown with a small table of optins.

Put a list of fruits in column **C**, a list of dogs in column **D** and a list of cats in column **E**. The DV dropdown in cell **A1** will allow the user to select either "fruit" or "dog" or "cat".

In cell **A2** we setup Data Validation with the List option and the formula:

```
=IF(A1="fruit",C1:C4,IF(A1="dog",D1:D4,E1:E4))
```

[image]

Now if you pick a category in **A1**, cell **A2** will have a DV for that catagory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not one single list but does work:
[image]

Cells D4:D7 update based on the category chosen.
Then the Item can be selected from the appropriate list.