# How to make a dependent dropdown list in excel, of a list of variable size

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 5 separate sheets in excel

number 1 list foods like this:

| Food type | Food |
| --- | --- |
| Nuts |  |
|  | Hazelnut |
|  | Cashew |
|  | Walnut |
| Fruit |  |
|  | Banana |
|  | Apple |

It allows the user to input foods and divide them by type.

The second sheet is the same but with unhealthy foods.

The third sheet is generated using functions and should not be touched by the user. It looks like this:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nuts | Hazelnut | Cashew | Walnut |
| Fruit | Banana | Apple |  |

It lists all food types in the first sheet and then places the foods in that category behind it.
The fourth sheet is the same but for the unhealthy foods.
Sheets 3 and 4 were made using the solutions to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76939211/i-need-to-rearrange-cell-values-according-to-certain-conditions-in-excel)

And now to the final sheet. I want to make it a sort of logbook of when I bought which foods. Like this:

| Date | Amount | Category | Food type | Food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/09/08 | 5 | Healthy | Nuts | Cashew |
| 2023/10/09 | 2 | Healthy | Fruit | Apple |

The hard part here is that I want the entries in the last three columns to be options from lists. The category is easy, I have that figured out. But how do I make a list of all food types in the healthy sheet when healthy is selected in the category column, or all unhealthy food types when unhealthy is selected? And then once a food type is selected make a list of all foods that belong to it?

It is important to note that sheets 1 and 2 can be edited over time, sheets 3 and 4 are updated automatically and the dropdown menus of sheet 5 should automatically adapt.

Comment: You might want to look at the choose() function - did something similar with it... Or check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64714109/4961700

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1:** Create a named range for the "Healthy" dynamic array on Sheet3. To do this, select the top-left cell of the spilled array, which contains the formula (I'm going to assume it's cell A1), then go to the **Formulas Tab** on the ribbon and click **Define Name**. In the **Name:** field, type *Healthy*, then in the **Refers to:** field, add the hashtag symbol (#) to the end of the cell reference `=Sheet3!$A$1#` and click OK.

**STEP 2:** Repeat step 1 to create a named range for the "Unhealthy" dynamic array on Sheet4 (**Name:** *Unhealthy*, **Refers to:** `=Sheet4!$A$1#`).

**STEP 3:** Create a custom LAMBDA function called "GET.LIST". Again, on the **Formulas Tab**, click **Define Name**. In the **Name:** field, type *GET.LIST*, but this time in the **Refers to:** field, copy and paste the following formula, then click OK:

```
=LAMBDA(category,[food_type],
   LET(
   _list, INDIRECT(category),
   _types, INDEX(_list,,1),
   _items, DROP(_list,,1),
   IF(ISOMITTED(food_type),_types,
      XLOOKUP(food_type,_types,_items))))
```

**STEP 4:** Add data validation to the "Food Type" column (D) on Sheet5. To do this, select the range D2:D10 (or however many rows you need), then go the **Data Tab** on the ribbon and click the **Data Validation** icon. Under **Allow:** select *List*, then for the **Source:** use the custom function `=GET.LIST(C2)`.

**STEP 5:** Repeat step 4 to add data validation to the "Food" column (E2:E10) on Sheet5, but this time for the **Source:** use the custom function `=GET.LIST(C2,D2)`.

**NOTE:** When you click OK to create the data validation rules, you may be prompted with the following message:

> The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?

Click Yes to proceed, and the dependent data validation lists should work as expected (select a category of either "Healthy" or "Unhealthy" in C2 to generate the dependent list in D2, then select an item in D2 to generate the dependent list in E2).